# React.js - How can I make setInterval know when a variable has changed its state/value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, face-api

Below is my relevant Javascript code -

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
    ]).then(()=> {
      if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia({ audio:false, video:true })
          .then((stream) => {
            console.log(stream)
            const video = document.getElementById("video");
            videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
            console.log("video is " + video)
            video.play();
            setisLoaded(true);
            addEvent();
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      }
    });
    }, []);

      const addEvent = () => {
        console.log("Inside")
        const video = document.getElementById("video");
        video.addEventListener("play", () => {
          const canvas = faceapi.createCanvas(video);
          canvas.id = "canvas";
          document.querySelector("#video").append(canvas);
          document.body.append(canvas);
          const displaySize = { width:width, height:height };
          faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
          setInterval(async () => {
            const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces('video', new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
            const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
            canvas
              .getContext("2d")
              .clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
            if(resizedDetections[0].expressions && tracking) {
              setData(arr => [...arr, resizedDetections[0].expressions]);
            }
          }, 100);
        })
      }
```

The if statement in the setInterval function always evaluates the tracking state variable as false. The tracking variable is initially set to false, but I later change the state to true (in a function that is not shown). However, the setInterval function still evaluates the tracking variable to be false.

Is there any way for me to ensure the setInterval function knows when a variable or state changes?

I tried using a localStorage variable and even the useRef react hook, but got the same result. I tried using the [useInterval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/beautiful-react-hooks) hook as well, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the full example as your useEffect is not full. I don't see dependencies. Are you sure that `tracking` is part of `useEffect` dependencies?

In general useEffect will not update values of variables that are not part of dependencies array. This is most likely the issue here.

It worth mentioning that adding `tracking` as part of dependencies list will cause you to reload models on change. So you will need to add extra checks or refactor this useEffect. You might also need to call `video.removeEventListener` for cleanup

Docs: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect